# What monsters drop level two clue scrolls?

Tags: runescape

I want to get some good loot, and I know clue scrolls are a good way to get good items. I know how to get Lv 1 clue scrolls, but I do not know what monster drop Lv 2 ones. Also, could you tell me the item requirements for Lv 2 scrolls(Shovels, sextants, ect. ect.).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This page](http://www.tip.it/runescape/?rs2monster_tools=1&advanced_search=1&dung_monster=0&drops=Clue%20scroll&suffix=medium&search=Search) has a list of all monsters that drop Level 2 (medium difficulty) clue scrolls. For completeness, [these monsters](http://www.tip.it/runescape/?rs2monster_tools=1&advanced_search=1&dung_monster=0&drops=Clue%20scroll&suffix=easy&search=Search) drop easy clue scrolls, [these](http://www.tip.it/runescape/?rs2monster_tools=1&advanced_search=1&dung_monster=0&drops=Clue%20scroll&suffix=hard&search=Search) drop hard clue scrolls, and [these](http://www.tip.it/runescape/?rs2monster_tools=1&advanced_search=1&dung_monster=0&drops=Clue%20scroll&suffix=elite&search=Search) drop elite clue scrolls. In addition, as [this page](http://www.tip.it/runescape/?page=treasure_trails_basics.htm) says, there are a couple of other ways to get medium clue scrolls, including Shades of Mort'ton chests (Steel and Black), caskets from big net fishing, Manage Thy Kingdom, Evil Trees, and Trouble Brewing.